# How to copy a Specific Partitioned Table

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I would like to shift data from a specific paritioned table of parent to separate table.Can someone suggest what's the better way.

If I create a table

`CREATE TABLE parent columns(a,b,c)partition by c`

c Type is DATE.

`CREATE TABLE dec_partition PARTITION OF parent FOR VALUES FROM '2021-02-12' to 2021-03-12;`

Now I want to copy table `dec_partition` to separate table in single command with least time.

**NOTE: The table has around 4million rows with 20 columns (1 of the column is in jsonb)**

Comment: `create table separate_table as select * from dec_partition`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name will it be efficient than pg_dump

Comment: That's as fast as it gets